# jquery get value of >THIS</a>

Tags: jquery

i have the following HTML

```
 //a href="/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentPreferences" title="Edit personal preferences">Admin OTRS //a>
```

Using JQUERY i want to get "Admin OTRS"

I have tried

```
 alert($('a[href$="AgentPreferences"]:first').attr(name));
```

and

```
 $('a[href$="AgentPreferences"]:first').attr('title');
```

and

```
 alert($('a[href$="AgentPreferences"]:first').attr(src));
```

but nothing gives me the Admin OTRS field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to read the text

```
alert($('a[href$="AgentPreferences"]:first').text());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6xZX6/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
alert($('a[href$="AgentPreferences"]:first').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple magic word is `text()` like

```
var ancVal = $('a[href$="AgentPreferences"]:first').text();
alert(ancVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
alert($('a[href$="AgentPreferences"]:first').html())
```

OR

```
alert($('a[href$="AgentPreferences"]:first').text());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jv76G/4/)